# Permanently magnify the content displayed in Firefox

Tags: linux, linux-mint, display, mate-desktop, dpi

I'm using Linux Mint 17.1 MATE. On of the users of the computer have troubles with eyesight and seeing very small text. I increased the DPI of the whole text in `RMB > Change Desktop Background > Fonts > Details > Resolution` to 132 DPI.

Still, the pages in Firefox keep displaying at the same size as on another account, configured to 96 DPI (default).

How could I permanently magnify the pages in Firefox for that specific user? Is there any better way to magnify the whole UI without changing the screen resolution?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways, but I think the easiest is to install the [NoSquint Extention](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nosquint/), which lets you set a default zoom level (for text and overall separately, if needed), and also makes it easy to adjust on a site-by-site basis.